# Under a composite key unique constraint, does EACH value need to be unique (or just the combination)?

Tags: sql, constraints, unique-constraint

I think this is a very basic question - so basic that I haven't been able to find an answer.

Let's say that two columns compose a composite key unique constraint: `col_a` and `col_b`.

Can two rows share a common value for `col_a`, as long as the combination of values for `col_a` and `col_b` are different? Or does each column need to be unique (like two separate UNIQUE constraints would require)?

Comment: You could've found the answer by simply trying it.  Create a unique composite key, and add values that you think should work or not work.

Comment: Understood - I'm in the process of learning the fundamentals of SQL, and I had the question prior to studying the syntax and mechanics of constraint definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a unique composite key, then only the combination of column values has to be unique.